# Proton BlockingConnection Listen Claims on Azure Service bus

Tags: python-3.x, azure-web-app-service, azureservicebus

I get the following error messages:

```
'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb:/XXXXX.servicebus.windows.net/queue

proton._utils.LinkDetached: receiver 21881c3f-a71a-41fc-92c5-4a8d82956cdf from queue closed due to: Condition('amqp:unauthorized-access', "Unauthorized access.

'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation.'
```

I have listen claims setup. Not sure what I am doing wrong. The same python code when run from a separate vm works fine. I can send a message to the queue.

However only when I am running the code from an app service I hit the Listen Claims error. I am using the proton qpid python library. I am passing the keyname and key to the connection string...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately this question is barely readable. You most likely won't get any helpful answers. Please read [How to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail this may be hard to gander a precise fix, but some thoughts come to mind, because, candidly, I trust that error (especially if it worked from another machine.)

1. You've checked that the queue and key bits are making it into the app service intact?
2. You've checked the connection string is formatted correctly, since you mention "passing the keyname to the connection string"; making me wonder if you built it by hand rather than copying from the portal. (and if so, if it could have gotten mangled)
3. (at this point I'm totally guessing) Perhaps qpid is picky about talking to entity. vs namespace level connection strings?

I can't even really expect firewall/network failures, that would likely manifest TOTALLY differently.

My next debugging steps would involve trying to validate the above, and trying to connect without the qpid intermediary, as I've seen other SO posts asking the same question (re Listen failure) but no followups, so perhaps there is an anomaly there; but my lack of familiarity with qpid makes it hard to do more than guess.

Don't hesitate to reach out on [our github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus) if you run into SDK related trouble in the future, full disclosure, am a maintainer for the python library.